# colcon build failure: 'Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ament_cmake"'

Tags: ubuntu

Any help appreciated :
I'm just trying to install Colcon on a virtual machine running ubuntu- and 
I'm using this command : `colcon build --symlink-install`

I'm getting this error:

```
Starting >>> sick_scan2
--- stderr: sick_scan2
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:24 (find_package):
By not providing "Findament_cmake.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this 
project
has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
"ament_cmake", but CMake did not find one.

 Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ament_cmake" 
with
any of the following names:

ament_cmakeConfig.cmake
ament_cmake-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "ament_cmake" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"ament_cmake_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"ament_cmake" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
has been installed.


---
Failed   <<< sick_scan2 [ Exited with code 1 ]

Summary: 0 packages finished [0.30s]
1 package failed: sick_scan2
1 package had stderr output: sick_scan2
```

Comment: The answer down is explained in detail [here](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Configuring-ROS2-Environment/)

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you didn't install some environment variables.

I had similar problem when I tried to build ROS2 project with Colcon.
But when I initially sourced my environment (something like `. ~ros2_ws/install/setup.bash)` it becomes fine.

P.S. If this problem in your case is also about ROS, don't forget to add installed libraries to classpath after building: `. install/setup.bash`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on a ROS2 project and got the same error message that you got. When I went into my works space and entered the command `source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash` from the foxy documentation https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html#environment-setup it then worked.
Hope this helps!